# {caret}xgTree: There were missing values in resampled performance measures

Tags: r, r-caret, xgboost, hyperparameters

I'm attempting to run a 5-fold XGBoost model on [this dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ptvlD8PZw9Xc87K6HeIoS5CE-1L68Z4t). When I run the following code:

```
  train_control<- trainControl(method="cv", 
                           search = "random", 
                           number=5,
                           verboseIter=TRUE)

  # Train Models 
  xgb.mod<- train(Vote_perc~.,
              data=forkfold, 
              trControl=train_control, 
              method="xgbTree", 
              family=binomial())
```

I receive a warning of:

```
Warning message:
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
```

Furthermore, the "predict" function runs, but all predictions were the same number. I suspect it's an intercept-only model, but I'm not sure. Also when I remove the

```
search="random"
```

argument, it runs properly. I want to run random searches so that I can isolate what hyperparameters might be most effective, but everytime I try, I get that warning. What am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: I am pretty sure neither caret train nor xgoost have a parameter `family=binomial()`. Perhaps u meant: `objective: "binary:logistic"` Also `Vote_perc` does not seem to be classes? Could you elaborate what you are attempting to do?

Comment: @missuse The Vote_perc column is a percentage of vote that I'm trying to predict. And it's possible that my syntax is wrong. Originally it was a beta regression and I've tried my best to convert it into an ML model from a purely statistical model, but I'm new to ML.

Comment: I double-checked and the `objective: "binary:logistic"` is xgboost notation, caret does use the `family=binomial()` that I had above. FWIW, changing it to `family=gaussian()` did NOT fix the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you saw the argument `family=binomial()` in caret `train` when running a `glm`? This is because caret passes arguments to the underlying function. Your target variable is not fit for classification - consider changing it to 0 and other than zero if that suits you. If not consider performing regression. Though given the omnipresence of zeros I doubt it can perform good.

Comment: I changed it to a binary classification response variable and the warning persisted. The phenomenon of the `predict()` function giving the same prediction for all observations persisted as well.

Comment: I added an answer depicting one possible approach.

Comment: Thank you! I understand the overall approach, but will need to review the literature in order to be more confident in exactly _why_ all those things were done. This certainly answers a larger part of my concern. If you'd indulge me for a moment, though, if my ultimate goal is to predict the "Vote_perc" variable, would I then need to resort to an xgbLinear method, despite the fact that the response variable is only intended to be a proportion between 0 and 1?

Comment: In this particular case I would first run a binary classifier to weed out the possible non zeros and then run a 2nd regression model. `xgbLinear` has nothing to do with that and is inferior to `xgbTree` so you should not use it. You can use `xgbTree` in a regression setting, however I would be weary to perform such a task on just 200 observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach you could perform with your data:

load data:

```
forkfold  <- read.csv("forkfold.csv", row.names = 1)
```

the problem here is that the outcome variable is 0 in 97% of the cases while in the remaining 3% it is very close to zero.

```
length(forkfold$Vote_perc)
#output
7069

sum(forkfold$Vote_perc != 0)
#output 
212
```

You described it a classification problem and I will treat it as such by converting it to a binary problem:

```
forkfold$Vote_perc <- ifelse(forkfold$Vote_perc != 0,
                             "one",
                             "zero")
```

Since the set is highly imbalanced using `Accuracy` as selection metric is out of the question. Here i will try to maximize `Sensitivity + Specificity` as described [here](https://topepo.github.io/caret/using-your-own-model-in-train.html) by defining a custom evaluation function:

```
fourStats <- function (data, lev = levels(data$obs), model = NULL) {
  out <- c(twoClassSummary(data, lev = levels(data$obs), model = NULL))
  coords <- matrix(c(1, 1, out["Spec"], out["Sens"]), 
                   ncol = 2, 
                   byrow = TRUE)
  colnames(coords) <- c("Spec", "Sens")
  rownames(coords) <- c("Best", "Current")
  c(out, Dist = dist(coords)[1])
}
```

I will specify this function in `trainControl`:

```
train_control <- trainControl(method = "cv", 
                              search = "random", 
                              number = 5,
                              verboseIter=TRUE,
                              classProbs = T,
                              savePredictions = "final",
                              summaryFunction = fourStats)

set.seed(1)
xgb.mod <- train(Vote_perc~.,
                 data = forkfold, 
                 trControl = train_control, 
                 method = "xgbTree", 
                 tuneLength = 50,
                 metric = "Dist",
                 maximize = FALSE,
                 scale_pos_weight = sum(forkfold$Vote_perc == "zero")/sum(forkfold$Vote_perc == "one"))
```

I will use the before defined `Dist` metric in the `fourStats` summary function. This metric should be minimized so `maximize = FALSE`. I will use a random search over the tune space and 50 random sets of hyper parameter values will be tested (`tuneLength = 50`).

I also set `scale_pos_weight` parameter of the xgboost function. From the help of [`?xgboost`](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html):

> scale_pos_weight, [default=1] Control the balance of positive and
>   negative weights, useful for unbalanced classes. A typical value to
>   consider: sum(negative cases) / sum(positive cases) See Parameters
>   Tuning for more discussion. Also see Higgs Kaggle competition demo for
>   examples: R, py1, py2, py3

I defined it as recommended `sum(negative cases) / sum(positive cases)`

After the model trains it will pick some hype parameters that minimize `Dist`.

To evaluate the confusion matrix on the hold out predictions:

```
caret::confusionMatrix(xgb.mod$pred$pred, xgb.mod$pred$obs)

Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  one zero
      one   195  430
      zero   17 6427

               Accuracy : 0.9368          
                 95% CI : (0.9308, 0.9423)
    No Information Rate : 0.97            
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1               

                  Kappa : 0.4409          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : <2e-16          

            Sensitivity : 0.91981         
            Specificity : 0.93729         
         Pos Pred Value : 0.31200         
         Neg Pred Value : 0.99736         
             Prevalence : 0.02999         
         Detection Rate : 0.02759         
   Detection Prevalence : 0.08841         
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.92855         

       'Positive' Class : one
```

I'd say its not that bad.

You can do better if you tune the cutoff threshold of predictions, how to do this during the tuning process is described [here](https://topepo.github.io/caret/using-your-own-model-in-train.html). You can also use the out of fold predictions for tuning the cutoff threshold. Here I will show how to use pROC library for it:

```
library(pROC)

plot(roc(xgb.mod$pred$obs, xgb.mod$pred$one),
     print.thres = TRUE)
```

[image]

The threshold shown on the image maximizes `Sens + Spec`:

to evaluate the out of fold performance using this threshold:

```
caret::confusionMatrix(ifelse(xgb.mod$pred$one > 0.369, "one", "zero"),
                       xgb.mod$pred$obs)
#output
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  one zero
      one   200  596
      zero   12 6261

               Accuracy : 0.914           
                 95% CI : (0.9072, 0.9204)
    No Information Rate : 0.97            
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1               

                  Kappa : 0.3668          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : <2e-16          

            Sensitivity : 0.94340         
            Specificity : 0.91308         
         Pos Pred Value : 0.25126         
         Neg Pred Value : 0.99809         
             Prevalence : 0.02999         
         Detection Rate : 0.02829         
   Detection Prevalence : 0.11260         
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.92824         

       'Positive' Class : one
```

So out of 212 non zero entities you detected 200.

To perform better you may try to pre process the data. OR use a better hyper parameter search routine like [`mlrMBO`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlrMBO/index.html) package intended for use with [`mlr`](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/release/html/). Or perhaps change the learner (I doubt you can top xgboost here tho).

One more note, if it is not paramount to get a high Sensitivity perhaps using "Kappa" as selection metric might provide a more satisfying model.

As a final note lets check the performance of the model with the default  `scale_pos_weight = 1`, using the already selected parameters:

```
set.seed(1)
xgb.mod2 <- train(Vote_perc~.,
                  data = forkfold, 
                  trControl = train_control, 
                  method = "xgbTree", 
                  tuneGrid = data.frame(nrounds = 498,
                                        max_depth = 3,
                                        eta = 0.008833468,
                                        gamma = 4.131242,
                                        colsample_bytree = 0.4233169,
                                        min_child_weight = 3,
                                        subsample = 0.6212512),
                  metric = "Dist",
                  maximize = FALSE,
                  scale_pos_weight = 1)

caret::confusionMatrix(xgb.mod2$pred$pred, xgb.mod2$pred$obs)
#output
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  one zero
      one    94   21
      zero  118 6836

               Accuracy : 0.9803          
                 95% CI : (0.9768, 0.9834)
    No Information Rate : 0.97            
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 3.870e-08       

                  Kappa : 0.5658          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 3.868e-16       

            Sensitivity : 0.44340         
            Specificity : 0.99694         
         Pos Pred Value : 0.81739         
         Neg Pred Value : 0.98303         
             Prevalence : 0.02999         
         Detection Rate : 0.01330         
   Detection Prevalence : 0.01627         
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.72017         

       'Positive' Class : one
```

So much worse at the default threshold of 0.5.

and the optimal threshold value:

```
plot(roc(xgb.mod2$pred$obs, xgb.mod2$pred$one),
     print.thres = TRUE)
```

[image]

0.037 compared to the 0.369 obtained when we set `scale_pos_weight` as recommended. However with the optimal threshold both approaches yield identical predictions.

Comment: Sorry, I tried your solution [in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74819967/there-were-missing-values-in-resampled-performance-measures), but I could not solve the issue. Thanks.